# Very long boot time on my Galaxy Nexus

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus, boot

My Galaxy Nexus 4.0.2 takes over three minutes to boot. Is this normal? Is it supposed to take this long to boot? Why does it take so long?

Comment: Shouldn't take that long... have you thought about trying a factory reset?

Comment: This is the phone I use every day and without a better reason that just trying a factory reset it is to much of a hassle. I will however try the factory reset if there is a problem that only can be solved that way. There are lots of stuff that needs to be downloaded, set-up and re synced.

Answer (score 2):

My Galaxy Nexus (I9250, GSM version) with Android 4.02 definitely doesn't take that long to boot.

Just switched mine off to test, and from off it takes just under a minute to get to the SIM card PIN unlock code screen (and after entering my PIN it goes straight to the pattern lock with my normal wallpaper).

Comment: Then it must be something wrong with my phone?

Answer (score 0):

You may have encrypted your phone contents. Both of my phones take a lot longer to boot since having to decrypt on start-up.